# convert bitmapsource to byte array in another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

i select some image and load them into bitmapimage in the main thread,now i want to save them to sqlserver database in another thread ( BackgroundWorker),But the following error occurs:

The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Notice : The DataType of target field is varbinary(max)

Sample Code:

```
class Class1
    {
        private List<BitmapSource> Items;
        public Class1()
        {
            this.Items = new List<BitmapSource>();
        }
        public void AddItem(BitmapSource bs)
        {
            this.Items.Add(bs);
        }
        public void Save()
        {
            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
            bw.RunWorkerAsync(this.Items);
        }

        void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            MyBLL bl = new MyBLL();
            bl.Save(e.Argument as List<BitmapSource>);
        }

    }

public class MyBLL
    {

        public byte[] ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(BitmapSource BS)
        {
            if (BS == null)
            {
                return new byte[] { };
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                JpegBitmapEncoder jbe = new JpegBitmapEncoder();

                jbe.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(BS.Clone()));
                jbe.Save(ms);
                return ms.GetBuffer();
            }
        }

        public void Save(List<BitmapSource> _items)
        {
            foreach (BitmapSource item in _items)
            {
                ---  insert  ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(item) to DataBase   ---
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: thanks . i add a sample code to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because your `BitmapSource` created on UI thread and you are trying to access its via another thread. To avoid this you need to change the method that converts `BitmapSource` to bytes to another that don't depend at `BitmapSource` or convert to bytes in UI thread.

Comment: ok ,but how can i convert BitmapSource to bytes to that don't depend at BitmapSource ???  i dont want to convert bitmapsource to bytes in the ui thread

Comment: Where do you get the `BitmapSource`s?

Comment: i get a image file of type BitmapSource from a custom class and bind it to ui , then pass it to AddItem method of Class1.

Comment: It would be better if a custom class returns an image as `Stream` (or other format that don't depend from UI) and then you can convert it to the `BitmapSource` to display in UI and use the `Stream` for convert.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to [Freeze](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557735.aspx) the BitmapSource to make it accessible from other threads, perhaps in AddItem:

```
public void AddItem(BitmapSource bs)
{
    bs.Freeze();
    this.Items.Add(bs);
}
```

Note also that it is not necessary to clone the BitmapSource before calling BitmapFrame.Create:

```
jbe.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(BS));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        Image yourImg = new Bitmap(1,1);
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((o,arg)=>{
            Image img = arg.Argument as Image;
            //Do whatever you want with your image
        });            
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(yourImg);//pass your image as a parameter to your sub-thread
```

Comment: thanks  but i want to pass a collection of BitmapSource that binded to the UI.